# Magento Display Curre

Tags: currency

In magento website i have two product segments in • one segment product Price to be displayed in Indian Rupee • while in another segment product Price to be displayed in Britain Pound. Base currency is Indian Rupee. Product having displayed in Britain Pound also to convert in base currency i.e.indian rupee at the time of payement in the shopping cart. there is no option in new product creation

Comment: In magento website i have two product segments in 
• one segment product Price to be displayed in Indian Rupee 
• while in another segment product Price to be displayed in Britain Pound.

Base currency is Indian Rupee.

Product having displayed in Britain Pound also to convert in base currency i.e.indian rupee at the time of payement in the shopping cart.

there is no option in new product creation<price to select display currency
by default it is accepting only base currency only - so, How to achieve this.

Please help.

Thank You

Comment: In magento 1.8.1.0 website i have ALL PRODUCTS FOR INDIAN CLIENTS.

• FEW PRODUCTS PRICE TO DISPLAY IN INDIAN RUPEES (INR) • FEW PRODUCTS PRICE TO DISPLAY IN BRITISH STERLING POUND (GBP - £) • FEW PRODUCTS PRICE TO DISPLAY IN US DOLLAR ($)

THIS ALL TO INCLUDE IN ONE DOMAIN SAY – WWW.MYDOMAINNAME.COM

NOW WHEN CLIENT ADD ANY OF ABOVE PRODUCT IRRESPECTIVE OF CURRENCY TO CART PRICE SHOULD GET CONVERTED INTO INDIAN RUPEES – BASE CURRENCY. I.E. ANY PRODUCTS CLIENT PURCHASE ULTIMATELY PAY IN INDIAN RUPEES 

HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS…..

Thank You